# how to enable motion sense in pixel 4 in India. using adb

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I found that we can enable motion sence in pixel 4 in India using ADB from here

https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/11/01/pixel-4-root-users-can-now-enable-motion-sense-in-restricted-countries/

I tried it but I getting an error

C:\Users\kanak\OneDrive\Desktop\LoseQuarantineFat>adb shell setprop pixel.oslo.allowed_override true
Failed to set property 'pixel.oslo.allowed_override' to 'true'.
See dmesg for error reason.

C:\Users\kanak\OneDrive\Desktop\LoseQuarantineFat>adb shell "setprop persist.pixel.oslo.allowed_override true; setprop ctl.restart zygote"
Failed to set property 'persist.pixel.oslo.allowed_override' to 'true'.
See dmesg for error reason.
Failed to set property 'ctl.restart' to 'zygote'.
See dmesg for error reason.

i also wanna know doing root is safe or not ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OsloFeedback, the app that’s responsible for handling Motion Sense gestures, has a hidden debug flag that disables all regional checks. With this debug flag set to true, your Pixel 4 will let you use the gestures no matter what carrier your SIM card is connected to.

In order to set this flag, you’ll need to **first** [**unlock the bootloader and root your phone with Magisk**](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-4-root-magisk/).

To enable the sensor, you will need to run adb command: `adb shell setprop pixel.oslo.allowed_override true` to enable it temporarily **OR** run `adb shell “setprop persist.pixel.oslo.allowed_override true; setprop ctl.restart zygote”` to enable the sensor permanently.

**Disclaimer**: Pixel 4’s motion sensors use radar technology which is governed at a national level. Enabling the senor without the explicit approval from the government is illegal and can get you in trouble. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: this isn't working